# How to make flatlist grow to fill the entire screen?

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

Using **react-native-gifted-chat**. With only one message, the Flatlist doesn't take up the entire screen, causing the message to look weird when scrolling down (see picture). How do I make the list grow to fill the entire screen?

```html
 <View style={styles.container}>
  <GiftedChat
    messages={this.state.messages}
    onSend={this.onSend}
    alwaysShowSend
    minInputToolbarHeight={60}
    bottomOffset={0}
    alignTop
  />
 </View>
const styles = EStyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  }
})
```

[image]

Comment: Identical to this issue: https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/issues/1227

Comment: Can you share some of your code?

Comment: @CarlosAbraham yes edited the post to show my code

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me. Set the property `alignTop` `false`,  Using `flex: 1` for `SafeA` to make sure FlatList take all up all the screen.

```
 <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
    <GiftedChat
      messages={this.state.messages}
      onSend={this.onSend}
      alignTop={false}/>
  </SafeAreaView>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
 },
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to alignTop the items so I cant set it to false :/

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to figure this out if you still need to have `alignTop={ true }`. It requires a small tinker with the node-module itself.

Go to `node_modules > react-native-gifted-chat > lib > MessageContainer.js`.

Under `styles`, for `containerAlignTop`, add `flex: 1`.
For `contentContainerStyle`, change `justifyContent: 'flex-start'` to `justifyContent: 'flex-end'`.

So it should look like this:

```
containerAlignTop: {
  flexDirection: 'row',
  alignItems: 'flex-start',
  flex: 1
},
contentContainerStyle: {
 flexGrow: 1,
 justifyContent: 'flex-end'
}
```

That should work.

Comment: Editing node_modules is not recommended, it will be replaced when you add/update other modules. You might want to fork the library and made changes as you need and then use it in your app.